# How to write a scalable, maintainable and DRY library tree-like type with generics in TS?

Tags: typescript, generics

### TL;DR

I need a type in my library that will look something like this:

```
const myProjectLinks: LinkMap<Region, Platform> = {
  global: {       // Region
    ios: 'a',     // Platforms
    android: 'b',
    huawei: 'c',
  },
  us: {
    ios: 'd',
  },
};
```

That has to be: scalable, maintainable and DRY

### The issue

I'm preparing a component for extraction into a library and it's got some complex types. The final object should be like the one above. But the LinkMap type is currently bound to the project. It defines the list of regions and a list of links:

```
export enum LinkPlatform {
  Ios = 'ios',
  Android = 'android',
  Huawei = 'huawei',
}

export enum LinkRegion {
  Global: 'global',
  Us: 'us',
}

export type LinkMap = {
  [key in LinkRegion]?: {
    [key in LinkPlatform]?: string;
  };
};
```

It has problems:

- Code duplication: fields with same name but using different case
- Impossible to automatically and safely rename strings in IDEs
- Impossible to remove or add new values without changes to the library

### What I've tried

I tried generics, literals and types. Every approach fails in one or two of the issues listed above.

##### Generics and Literal types

Code duplication, partially impossible to rename:

```
// Library side
type LinkMap<Env extends string, Store extends string> = {
  [Key in Env]: {
    [Key in Store]?: string;
  };
};

// Project side
// can only rename the keys, not the values, no hints how to define anything
const enum LinkRegion { 
type
  Global = 'global',
  Us = 'us',
}

// impossible to refactor the values automatically
type LinkPlatform = 'ios' | 'android' | 'huawei';

// Type safe
const myProjectLinks: LinkMap<LinkRegion, AppLinkPlatform> = {
  global: {
    ios: '',
    android: '',
    huawei: '',
  },
  us: {
    ios: '',
  },
};
```

##### Types

Illegal amounts of useless `any`s

```
// Library side
type LinkMap<Region extends { [Key in keyof Region]: any }, Platform extends string> = {
  [Key in keyof Region]: {
    [Key in Region]?: string;
  };
};

// Project side
type LinkRegion = {
  global: any; // useless any, never to be used, also no hints
  us: any;
};

// ...
```

Comment: "Impossible to refactor" means what, exactly? What amount of code makes it "illegal"? I'm worried that this might be too unfocused or too subjective to be acceptable for Stack Overflow. Could you [edit] to clarify the criteria for success and how we can objectively determine if a suggestion meets them?  I'm particularly confused by the requirements for renaming in an IDE; which IDE, what counts as "automatic"/"safe", and is this something you're doing often enough that optimizing the process is particularly important (e.g., why does a text find/replace with a little user guidance not suffice)?

Comment: Which IDE: VSCode, PHPStorm. In VSC it's just impossible to rename the values so that they also change in the constants, in PHPStorm it's only partially automatic, making the code less maintainable. 

Yes, it is important to make it as maintainable as possible. 

Find/replace this string in your project: "us"

Comment: I would use regex like `\bus\b` and deal with the occasional instance of the word "us" in the documentation ‍♂️.  How often are you renaming these entities such that you need to make sure this process is automatic?  I'll take your word for it that you do have such a requirement, but it seems very strange to me.  Anyway, does VSCode sometimes have the ability to rename things the way you want? Does it only work for interface keys or something? I'm still not sure that the question delineates criteria for success in a way that others can verify for themselves.